# How to calculate the distance between two points in meters on a sphere surface?

Tags: math, coordinates, distance, latitude-longitude, haversine

May I ask that is it possible to calculate the distance between two points whose coordinates are in meters (Example: A(3500 m, 1151 m) and B(2500 m, 1020 m)) on a sphere like the earth's surface?

I already searched some methods like haversine distance but it is mostly used with longitude and latitude.

Comment: How are the two coordinates of `A` and `B` being interpreted? Generally, you need three points to determine a point in space.

Comment: You may need to tag the language, because I recommend you to use a existing library: it is not easy to implement mathematical functions and keeping precision. In any case, you should convert to lat/long (according your datum), or you should check if your national geographic office (or university) has found a good way to use directly meter coordinates (numeric mathematics is not easy, and it requires a lot of guesses).

Comment: But: why not using a flat surface distance? In your example you have short distances, so the error should be minimal (and also with haversine you have approximations)

Comment: Ah, right; these are simply planar coordinates? In that case you need to know the projection that's in use (e.g., transverse Mercator, ...). Without that information you're not going to be able to convert to points on the sphere. But as @GiacomoCatenazzi says, do you really need the spherical distance? Your points are so close together that the error would be minimal (and likely much less than error due to difference in elevation, for example). There are libraries like [PROJ](https://proj.org) for working with projections.

Comment: That's assuming that you don't just mean "a sphere *like* the Earth's surface", but that you're actually working with the Earth's surface (which is generally better approximated by an ellipsoid rather than a sphere).